# SQL Server 2012 Data Recovery

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, data-recovery

I just recently had a Sharepoint server die out on me a really old `Sharepoint 3.0 server.`

I was able to recover all the `.mdf` and `.ldf` sql database files since the previous admin didn't make backups of it.  How can I extract the word documents, excel documents and pdfs etc off of these databases?

I have installed windows server 2008 on an old pc with sql server management studio and SQL 2012.

Comment: Have you successfully restored the database?

Comment: I successfully attached the database with sql management to a new database setup.  The database I attached was the WSS content databases.  I am hoping those are the 2 that need to be attached since they are 28 Gigs and 1.9 Gigs in size.